# recurrence relations and explicit formula discrepancy

Tags: discrete-mathematics

During a problem I got $K_n=2K_{n-1}+3K_{n-2}$ and $K_2=3,$ $K_3=6$. Using the characteristic equation,
$$x^2-2x-3=0$$
$$x=3,-1$$
So $$K_n=a(3)^n+b(-1)^n$$
Which results to from $K_2, K_3$
$$K_n=\frac{3^n+3(-1)^n}{4}$$
However suppose n=10. By the explicit formula we get 14763, but our recursive relation gives 10,941. What is causing this discrepancy?

For context the problem is

> There are 4 people passing a ball between each other. If person A starts passing the ball, how many ways can the ball get back to A in 10 passes?

Comment: Your formula is ok.

Comment: Check again a recusion result...

Comment: You're given $K_2, K_3$. So for using recurrence to find $K_{10}$ you have to iterate only $7$ times. Not $10$ times.

Comment: I get $14,763$ from the recurrence.

Comment: Sorry for my stupid question.